# How do I see a list of all my resources in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

How do I see a list of all my resources in Civ 6 - and where they are going (I understand that each is spread automatically to up to 4 cities?).

I need to prioritise which resource to get next, including duplicates.

Civilopedia is no help - nor is Google. Thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see a list of all your luxury, strategic and bonus resources by clicking on "Reports" `(1)` in the top left bar and choosing the "resources" tab `(2)`.

This will show how many resources you currently have available. `(3)`

[image: Where to find the buttons]

I have not noticed a way to see in which city your luxuary resources are currently used. But your understanding is correct. Each available luxuary creates 1 amenity in the 4 lowest-happiness cities.

Comment: thanks - do you know why bonus resources are also listed? I thought they only gave thing slike extra food and not amenities??

Comment: There's several wonders that must be placed near a particular bonus resource.  I imagine seeing bonus resources you control could be useful for that.  It would be very useful if you could zoom to the resource from this screen.

Comment: Honestly, it seems like a "lazy programmer approach" where they just included all resources. I really can't see any use for listing the bonus resources there.

Comment: Its funny when you have so much resources, that they expand far over your screen

Comment: Note from the future - they separated resources and bonus resources now

Comment: Not sure when but the **View Reports** button has been replaced with a **List of Reports** round button on  the top-right immediately to the right of what looks like a "refresh" button (though actually to do with trade routes).  Fine answer though :)

Comment: This was done in Gathering Storm